# AngularJS auto convert link in text variable to clickable link

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the below HTML, to display all `article` in `listAllArticle`. The article `description` field can sometimes contains a link. Now I want to convert the link to an `href` that is clickable. An example of the description `I love wwww.google.com`, here the url should be converted to a `<a>` element with `href` to the link

```
           <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Content</th>


                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="article in listAllArticles" ng-class-even="'info'" ng-class-odd="'success'">
                    <td col-2>{{ article.title }}</td>
                    <td col-2><div ng-bind-html="article[description ] | linky"></div></td>
                    <td col-4>{{ article.content }}</td>

                </tr>
```

**Attempt**: I have followed this guide to use AngularJS [linky](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/filter/linky). In the above, I have put `<div ng-bind-html="article[url] | linky"></div>` to be converted.

Also, in my js file, I have also included `ngSantitize` as below:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
```

Yet the result is not displayed (it shows empty). Could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Html just change **article[description]** to **article.description**. And it will work the way you are expecting.

Final HTML Code will look like:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
     <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Content</th>
     </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat="article in listAllArticles" ng-class-even="'info'" ng-class-odd="'success'">
            <td col-2>{{ article.title }}</td>
            <td col-2><div ng-bind-html="article.description | linky"></div></td>
            <td col-4>{{ article.content }}</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

This is the test data used:

```
$scope.listAllArticles = [
            {
                title:"",
                description:"I love www.google.com",
                content:""
            }
        ]
```